# Getting error in Angular 2 while starting project

Tags: angular, npm

I am new to angular 2. I have setup my project and trying to start it via npm, previously it was working fine then after some days when I am starting it, its giving the following error in command prompt.

```
SyntaxError: Unexpected token {
at exports.runInThisContext (vm.js:53:16)
at Module._compile (module.js:374:25)
at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:417:10)
at Module.load (module.js:344:32)
at Function.Module._load (module.js:301:12)
at Module.require (module.js:354:17)
at require (internal/module.js:12:17)
at Object.<anonymous> (/home/ahmer/practice/gmail-angular2/node_modules/@ngtools/webpack/src/index.js:5:10)
at Module._compile (module.js:410:26)
at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:417:10)
at Module.load (module.js:344:32)
at Function.Module._load (module.js:301:12)
at Module.require (module.js:354:17)
at require (internal/module.js:12:17)
at Object.<anonymous> (/home/ahmer/practice/gmail-angular2/node_modules/angular-cli/models/webpack-build-typescript.js:3:17)
at Module._compile (module.js:410:26)
at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:417:10)
at Module.load (module.js:344:32)
at Function.Module._load (module.js:301:12)
at Module.require (module.js:354:17)
at require (internal/module.js:12:17)
at Object.<anonymous> (/home/ahmer/practice/gmail-angular2/node_modules/angular-cli/models/webpack-config.js:2:34)
at Module._compile (module.js:410:26)
at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:417:10)
at Module.load (module.js:344:32)
at Function.Module._load (module.js:301:12)
at Module.require (module.js:354:17)
at require (internal/module.js:12:17)
at Object.<anonymous> (/home/ahmer/practice/gmail-angular2/node_modules/angular-cli/tasks/build-webpack.js:6:24)
at Module._compile (module.js:410:26)
at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:417:10)
at Module.load (module.js:344:32)
at Function.Module._load (module.js:301:12)
at Module.require (module.js:354:17)
at require (internal/module.js:12:17)
at Object.<anonymous> (/home/ahmer/practice/gmail-angular2/node_modules/angular-cli/commands/build.js:4:23)
at Module._compile (module.js:410:26)
at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:417:10)
at Module.load (module.js:344:32)
at Function.Module._load (module.js:301:12)
at Module.require (module.js:354:17)
at require (internal/module.js:12:17)
at Class.module.exports.includedCommands (/home/ahmer/practice/gmail-angular2/node_modules/angular-cli/addon/index.js:21:16)
at /home/ahmer/practice/gmail-angular2/node_modules/angular-cli/ember-cli/lib/models/project.js:335:61
at Array.forEach (native)
at Project.addonCommands (/home/ahmer/practice/gmail-angular2/node_modules/angular-cli/ember-cli/lib/models/project.js:334:15)
at Project.eachAddonCommand (/home/ahmer/practice/gmail-angular2/node_modules/angular-cli/ember-cli/lib/models/project.js:369:30)
at module.exports (/home/ahmer/practice/gmail-angular2/node_modules/angular-cli/ember-cli/lib/cli/lookup-command.js:33:13)
at CLI.<anonymous> (/home/ahmer/practice/gmail-angular2/node_modules/angular-cli/ember-cli/lib/cli/cli.js:43:26)
at tryCatch (/home/ahmer/practice/gmail-angular2/node_modules/rsvp/dist/rsvp.js:538:12)
at invokeCallback (/home/ahmer/practice/gmail-angular2/node_modules/rsvp/dist/rsvp.js:553:13)
at publish (/home/ahmer/practice/gmail-angular2/node_modules/rsvp/dist/rsvp.js:521:7)
at flush (/home/ahmer/practice/gmail-angular2/node_modules/rsvp/dist/rsvp.js:2373:5)
at nextTickCallbackWith0Args (node.js:419:9)
at process._tickCallback (node.js:348:13)
```

Any idea how to resolve it ??

Comment: copy your code here

Comment: update your package.json to post

Comment: @Kuncevic which code ?

Comment: @Aravind how can I convert to post ??

Comment: try npm install

Comment: @AhmerKhan click on the edit option below the post and update

Answer (score 0):

I believe you have created your project with little older angular CLI version. 
I myself had that same error after I updated my angular cli version to latest. Angular CLI was updated while ago so it requires node version 6.9.0 or higher and npm version 3 or higher.
https://github.com/angular/angular-cli#prerequisites

tldr: you have to update your node version